# Are pork trotters or foot and pork knuckles the same thing?

Tags: pork, food-identification

Are pork trotters or foot, and pork knuckles the same thing? What are the differences?

Answer (score 12):

These are distinct pieces of a pig. A pork foot is the actual foot, including the toes, as can be seen for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig%27s_trotter).

A pork knuckle on the other hand is the join just above the feet, also called ham hock or Eisbein when used in German cooking. Again [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisbein) has a nice picture showing that this is a slightly different piece.

From a culinary perspective, a pork knuckle contains a lot of meat/ muscle as well as skin and bones. A pork foot is almost exclusively bones and skin with very little meat in between.

Comment: Thanks. I can't open Wikipedia till someone helps me climb over GFW.

Comment: A foot/trotter has limited meat (i.e. enough for a decent sandwich rather than a decent meal), but is very good for stock particularly if one has a pressure cooker.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I've eaten both port feet and pork knuckles. I'm not sure how you want to make a sandwich with a pork foot, the dishes I had were more based on the idea of cooking for a long time and then gnaw off  the skin from the bones. Both feet and knuckles will produce a huge amount of jelly if you cook them for long enough so yes they are good for stock/ hearty soup bases.

Comment: I think this would be a better alternative for your second link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_hock
Because this one points to the actual piece of meat, while yours points to a dish with that piece of meat.

Comment: @quarague Pressure cook, disassemble, save the limited amount of meat, put the remainder back in the cooker for a few more minutes to render down.

Answer (score 4):

Using this diagram from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schwein-Ganz.svg):

13 (front and back) are the hock or knuckle

14 (front and back) are the foot or trotter

[image]